# In material-ui using react select how to move focus to next control by pressing tab only once?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-select

By default in material-ui react-select after selecting option by tab or enter user need press tab twice to move focus to next element.

Below is the link for the demo

https://codesandbox.io/s/8xy53m60m2

Steps to repro:

1. Press tab to select option by highlighting option using arrow keys (focus is not moved to next component, Focus should move to next component)

2. When option is selected, user needs to press tab twice to focus next component.

Expected:

1.After selecting option from tab focus move to next component

2.After selecting option from mouse, focus should move to next component after pressing tab button once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how they designed to work,
There are two options to select dropdown elements `onenter` and `ontab` when you press the `tab` it selects that option it enters into input box (the focus is still in the select) and then to move to the next element you need to press the tab again.

Selection works that way only, for most of the packages.
If you want to disable tab selection behavior then is property called

```
tabSelectsValue
```

which is enabled by default, you can disable it

```
<Select        
    classes={classes}
    styles={selectStyles}
    options={suggestions}
    components={components}
    value={this.state.single}
    tabSelectsValue={false}
    onChange={this.handleChange("single")}
    placeholder="Search a country (start with a)"
    isClearable
/>
```

it will move the focus to next element, but then you will have to use enter to select the option.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/qvr4n446m6)

[Here](https://react-select.com/props#prop-types) is the full list of proptypes

Comment: Thanks for your input, But after using tabSelectsValue prop focus moves to next component as expected but option value is not select, Is there any way option is selected and focus moves to next component?

Comment: @Yasin that's what I said in the answer this is how it works.